# mongoTemplate fillter document array

Tags: mongotemplate

Using `mongoTemplate` in java Spring I tried this, but I don't keep document structure

Document as:

```json
{

   A :'a',
   B :'b',
   C : [
          { 
            name:'cat' ,  type :'animal'
          },
         { 
            name:'jonh' ,  type :'human'
          }
       ]
}
```

I want to keep document structure and filter  `c.type = 'animal'` like  below

Result example :

```json
{

   A :'a',
   B :'b',
   C : [
          { 
            name:'cat' ,  type :'animal'
          },
         
       ]

}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. It's not clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N6zhpmnERE7) where the document is not modified except for the filtering elements into `C` array where `type` is not `animal`.

So using MongoTemplate you can try something like this (not tested):

```java
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.set("C",
    Aggregation.filter("C", Criteria.where("type").is("animal"))
));

List<YourDocumentClass> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, YourDocumentClass.class).getMappedResults();
```